# SQL: Select count and percentage with conditions

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by, count, percentage, correlated-subquery

I have two tables

User

```
   id_user|INT
   company | varchar
```

and

Log

```
log_id|int
id_user|int
```

I need to return the company, the total number of users per company, and the percentage of users that have atleast 3 logs

I can run this query to get the company and counts

```
select company, count (*) as 'Count'
from user 
group by company
```

which returns this

```
Apple| 7
Google| 6
```

But I am having trouble figuring out how to then return an extra column that displays the percentage of those users that have at least 3 logs. For example, 
If there were 2 users who had more than 3 logs from Apple and one user from Google who had more than 3 logs, the answer would look like this:

```
Apple| 7| 29% (because 2/7=~29%)
Google| 6| 17% (because 1/7=~17%)
```

I figured this requires the use of windows function or some type of correlated subquery but I'm having issues accurately obtaining the correct percentage.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. (using SQL server 2008)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to do this without using window functions, though there is probably a version which would use them.  First, I aggregate the number of logs per user in a CTE.  Then, I join the user table to this, using conditional aggregation to count the number of users per company having 3 logs or more.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id_user, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM Log
    GROUP BY id_user
)

SELECT
    u.company,
    COUNT(DISTINCT u.id_user) AS total_users,
    100.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN c.cnt >= 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) /
        COUNT(DISTINCT u.id_user) AS log_3_users
FROM [User] u
LEFT JOIN cte c
    ON u.id_user = c.id_user
GROUP BY
    u.company;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that in the demo I just have some dummy data, where 1 out of 3 Google users has 3 or more logs, and 1 out of 2 Microsoft employees has 3 or more logs.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. It works! Appreciate the help

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you use a left join here? in the event that a user doesn't exist in log table that does in user table?

Comment: @nunga Yes, the left join means we won't drop any users should they have no logs.

Comment: `distinct` shouldn't be necessary I don't believe.